# How to call method from parent in Java?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Random;

class VehicleConstructor{

    private int startSpeed;

    public VehicleConstructor() {
        setSpeed();
        System.out.println("VehicleConstructor");
    }

    private void setSpeed(){
        int minSpeed = 1;
        int maxSpeed = 40;

        Random random = new Random();
        this.startSpeed = random.nextInt(maxSpeed - minSpeed + 1) + minSpeed;
    }
}

class Bicycle extends Vehicle{

    public Bicycle(){
        System.out.println(getSpeed());
    }
}

public class Vehicle{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Bicycle bicycle = new Bicycle();
    }
}
```

The problem is in `Bicycle` class where i try to call `getSpeed()` method from `VehicleConstructor` class. I also tried it with `this` and `super`. What is wrong?

Comment: So where is `getSpeed()` method?

Comment: *Facepalm*. You're inheriting *Vehicle*, not *VehiceConstructor*. We all look over dumb mistakes like this, but you should have looked at your code a bit first before you asked it here!

Comment: For future questions involving compiler errors, please be sure to include the exact code that causes the issue and the complete error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Bicycle` class currently extends `Vehicle`, and not `VehicleConstructor`. Extend `VehicleConstructor`, and create a `getSpeed()` method and your issues should be solved.

Comment: My fail... Need to sleep. Thanks a lot.

Comment: +1, though I'd be shocked if the current code for VehickeConstructor wasn't originally intended for Vehicle.

Answer (score 2):

There is no method named `getSpeed` in the code you've provided -- only a `setSpeed` -- and that method is `private`, which means it can't be accessed from any outside classes.

Answer (score 0):

`setSpeed()` is a method of `VehicleConstructor`, not `Vehicle`.

However, if it's a typo and `getSpeed()` is a method of `Vehicle`, you still cannot access it because it is declared as `private`. The minimum access modifiers that is required to access parent's method is `protected`.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that **getSpeed()** is not defined in **VehicleConstructor** class !!!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want this:

```
public class Vehicle{
    private int speed;
    public  void setSpeed(int speed){
        this.speed=speed;
    }

    public int getSpeed() {
        return speed;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want more something like this:

```
 class Vehicle{

    private int startSpeed;

    public Vehicle() {
        setSpeed();
        System.out.println("Vehicle");
    }

    private void setSpeed(){
        int minSpeed = 1;
        int maxSpeed = 40;

        Random random = new Random();
        this.startSpeed = random.nextInt(maxSpeed - minSpeed + 1) + minSpeed;
    }
    public int getSpeed(){ 
        return startSpeed; 
    } 
}

public class bicycle extends Vehicle{

    public Bicycle(){
        System.out.println(super.getSpeed());
    }

}

public class VehicleCostructor{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Bicycle bicycle = new Bicycle();

    }
}
```

Assuming that your VehicleConstructor was supposed to be a mere test to your classes.

A better way to test is, probably, using JUnit. Is an pretty useful and easy to use tool.

Hope this helped!